# Why does python thread stop working if I don't move my mouse?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have managed to execute the function through the thread, but after a few moments it stops working, until I move my mouse again, if I minimise the window, the thread will stop until I re-open the window.

```
import tkinter as tk,tkinter.ttk as ttk, pyautogui, numpy as np, easygui, cv2, os, sys, re, math, subprocess, threading, requests, PIL.Image, random, time
```

Function I am trying to run through the thread

```
 def runScript(self):
        def on_release(key):
            if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
                print('test')
                return False
        listener = keyboard.Listener(
            on_release=on_release)
        listener.start()
        
##        self.toplevel1.iconify()
        e1 = lb_0.get()
        if loopVar.get() == True:  
                if moveVar.get() == True and randVar.get() == True:
                        while loopVar.get() == True:
                            for i in range(len(e1)):
                                e1, e2, e3, e4 = lb_0.get(), lb_1.get(), lb_2.get(), lb_3.get()
                                xyCoor1 = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', str(e1[i]))]
                                xyCoor2 = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', str(e2[i]))]
                                cCoor1 = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', str(e3[i]))]
                                iCoor1 = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', str(e4[i]))]
                                randLoc = int(randText.get().strip())
                                randX1 = int(xyCoor1[0] - int(randLoc) / 2)
                                print('w')
                                randX2 = int(xyCoor1[0] + int(randLoc) / 2)
                                randY1 = int(xyCoor2[0] - int(randLoc) / 2)
                                randY2 = int(xyCoor2[0] + int(randLoc) / 2)
                                trueX = int(random.randint(randX1,randX2))
                                trueY = int(random.randint(randY1,randY2))
                                print(trueX)
                                print(trueY)
                                pyautogui.PAUSE = iCoor1[0]
                                pyautogui.moveTo(x=trueX, y=trueY, duration=0.05, _pause=False)
                                pyautogui.click(x=trueX, y=trueY, clicks=cCoor1[0], button='left')
```

function that creates the thread

```
    def threadRunScript(self, event):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.runScript)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    pass
```

button that points to function

```
        #Run script button
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self.labelframe1)
        self.button3.configure(activeforeground='#000000', font='{Century Gothic} 13 {}', foreground='#fefffe', highlightbackground='#393a4c')
        self.button3.configure(highlightcolor='#2e2a2e', highlightthickness='100', justify='center', relief='raised', command=self.threadRunScript)
        self.button3.configure(image=imgToButton4("/Users/giuseppemarziano/Desktop/Scripts/Personal Projects/Auto Click GM/ACGM 0.04/ACGM Images/start.svg"))
        self.button3.place(anchor='nw', height='25', relx='0.0', rely='0.0', width='25', x='320', y='4')
        self.button3.bind('<1>', self.threadRunScript, add='+')
```

top of class

```
class Acgm003App(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
```

Main loop

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Acgm003App()
    app.run()
```

I have tried to use `queue.Queue`, but it won't let me do it without passing arguments, I've also, tried to do something like `self.toplevel1.after(1000, self.update())`, but it wouldn't work properly.

Is there an easy way to either keep the function going or refresh the gui at given intervals to allow the Thread to not be interrupted?

Comment: didn't read entirely but this would be the proper way (in most cases): `self.toplevel1.after(1000, self.update)`

Comment: @Matiss, where would I put this? In the main function where I build the objects, or in the function that I want to thread?

Comment: `tkinter` is single threaded, not recommended to use threading on it.

Comment: @CoolCloud, what is the best way to stop the window from freezing?

Comment: Use another thread :p

Comment: @CoolCloud that is what I'm doing but the issue is, if I don't move my mouse the thread stops doing anything, or if I lose focus on the window, the thread stops,

Comment: If `Acgm003App` class contains the tkinter stuff, it is better not running it in a thread, i.e. don't inherit from `threading.Thread`.

Comment: where would You put it? where You had it or sth I just made it functional (not calling the function straight away because then command will use it's return value which probably is `None`)

Comment: @Matiiss so I created a subclass to house all my "worker" functions, and put `threading.Thread` on that subclass, and put the functions I needed to thread in the secondary class, but after running I get `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it by adding the following in the main class:

```
self.mainwindow.after(10, self.updateMy)

    def updateMy(self):
        self.mainwindow.after(10, self.updateMy)
    pass
```

The above code will essentially create a loop every 10 milliseconds for the `root` to update itself.

I am unsure if this can cause any complications in terms of resources.

Comment: Glad you found your solution :D